# Full screen conversation when someone shares camera

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

I'm trying to put a conversation on fullscreen mode when someone shares it's camera, but i don't know what event handler should i be subscribed. Right now i'm subscribed to this event handlers:

```
AVModality.StreamStateChanged += AV_StreamStateChanged;
AVModality.ModalityStateChanged += AVModality_ModalityStateChanged;
VideoChannel.StateChanged += VideoChannel_StateChanged;
```

Comment: Also, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `VideoChannel.StateChanged`event. This event is under `Conversation.ParticipantAdded` event.

```
this.Conversation.PaticipantAdded += this.Conversation_ParticipantAdded;

private void Conversation_ParticipantAdded(object sender, ParticipantCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Participant.IsSelf) {
    }
    else {
      var avModality = e.Participant.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo] as AVModality;
      avModality.VideoChannel.StateChanged += this.ClientParticipant_VideoChannel_StateChanged;
    }
}

private void ClientParticipant_VideoChannel_StateChanged(object sender, ChannelStateChangedEventArgs e) {
 //Look for e.NewState
}
```

`e.NewState` can be used for listening channelstate enum. The details of enum can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.audiovideo.channelstate_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx).

Also have a look at [this link](http://unifiedpeople.ru/en_lync_2010_sdk.en/html/11f7e535-33fb-4118-8194-6d73f9e72c57.htm). It uses Lync SDK 2010, but still looks to be quite relevant.